# Between vs. Among - "Difference [between | among] one thing and other things."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, between-among

Consider the following two versions of a question:<sup>1</sup>

- **Version 1:** What is the difference in meaning **between** "[to be] not invited" and similar negation forms?
- **Version 2:** What is the difference in meaning **among** "[to be] not invited" and similar negated forms?

Personally, I think **Version 1** might subtly suggest a **Star Topology** (see below) with the target sentence "[to be] not invited" at the center.  And **Version 2** might subtly suggest a more free-form comparison like the **Mesh** or **Fully Connected**, with the target sentence simply "one among many":

[image: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NetworkTopologies.svg]
<sup>*Between* approx equal "Star" and *among* approx equal "Fully Connected"?</sup>

Don't get me wrong: I do think this is quite subtle, not always applicable, and I don't think anyone would *intuit* such a "network topology" meaning without further explanation.

**So the main question is, are both grammatically correct?  If yes, is there a semantic difference to choose one over another, perhaps as I suggested?  Or does the *plurality* aspect of *between* and *among* trump other semantic and stylistic issues?**

---

<sup>1. In my question [Does placement of "not" have significance? Not to be verb, To not be verb, To be not verb](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26520/does-placement-of-not-have-significance-not-to-be-verb-to-not-be-verb-to-be), another user provided a very helpful edit. However, the change of the word *between* to *among* prompted this question.</sup>

Comment: Here is how my brain works when I hear *between* and *among*. *Between* is about two things. This doesn't mean that there must be only two things in total. When there are more than two things, the *between* will make me think of each of the relations between all those things as a relation between each pair of them. On the other hand, *among* is about more than two things, and it makes me think of more complex relationships, where I can't think of the relation between each pair of those things clearly.

Comment: So I think the Star topology reminds me of *between*, while the Fully Connected can remind me of either *between* or *among* (though I think I still tend to think of the relationships as *between*; to think of it as *among*, I need something more messy). Consequently, I prefer the *between* version to the *among* one in your edited question. This is just my opinion, though.

Comment: If you have CGEL, check out page 636, "It is, rather, that with *between* the members of the set are considered individually, whereas with *among* they are considered collectively". See also this blog post, *[The real difference between “between” and “among”](http://motivatedgrammar.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/the-real-difference-between-between-and-among/)*, which I believe that it's amount to the same thing as the usage notes in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/between).

Comment: CGEL emphasizes individually vs. collectively, whereas the blog post and Wiktionary add vagueness (or as the post put it, "[*among* is used to express] a weaker, vaguer, more nebulous". I guess that my intuition is close enough to the ideas explained by the three sources. (Sorry that I'm too lazy to write an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky. Conjunctions and prepositions are among the most difficult meanings for semanticists to describe objectively, and this is why they often have the longest entries in dictionaries.

Note that in the previous sentence, *between* would not have worked in place of *among*.

***Between*** implicitly suggests a cline or planes of possibilities - it can be an *n*-dimensional plane, and whatever it is you're talking about lies somewhere in relation to other, points on it.

The very first sense of *['between' on Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/between)* echoes this sentiment:

> 1. at a point or in a region intermediate to two other points in space, times, degrees, etc

This is likely why you have intuited that between seems to suggest a *star topology* in network parlance.

***Among(st)***, on the other hand, is subtly different - it merely suggests a relationship to other things, without making claims to where it stands. If you consider a scatter plot, you could say that any of the points lies amongst others.

[image: A sample scatter plot]

There is the possible exception of outliers and those points which lie on the edge of the groups, but that becomes a much more difficult issue to manage, akin to [Sorites Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). My response to that is that the following sentence seems perfectly grammatical and sensible:

> He was the smartest by far among those students in his age group.

The definition for [among(st) on Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/among) suggests a couple of relationships:

> - in the midst of
> - in the group (of)

Of course, definitions can quickly become circular - that is, how does "in the midst of" differ from "between"? *In the midst of* seems to invoke a sense of positioning, rather than just that of relationships in general. The positioning can be based on anything, really, but *among* seems more felicitous when used in the description of vague constellations of meaning and relations, and *between* in those that are a bit more explicit.

"In the group of", on the other hand, is a much cleaner relationship.

Overall, the difference between *between* and *among* seems to be a fuzzy one - in the preceding clause, *among* would not have worked in place of *between*. I would say that *between* is better-suited for more explicit relationships, and *among(st)* for messier, more vague constellations of relations.

In the case of your two examples, I would say that the first means that you're comparing "[to be] not invited" with other forms. That is, "[to be] not invited" vs form-1, "[to be] not invited" vs form-2, etc.

If the question had read "what are the differences in meaning amongst negated forms (for example *[to be] not invited*)?", between/among(st) would both work well.

Comment: @user.jimsug, So which do you think is better? **Version 1** or **Version 2**?  Your answer has some very interesting points, but I'm having a little difficulty understanding if you have (or don't have) a preference for one or the other based on the points you have given. Thanks -

Comment: @CoolHandLouis answer edited.

Comment: Version 1 reads much better. "Difference among" doesn't really work as good English, because of the set relation I mentioned in my answer (which has been downvoted for some odd reason).

Comment: @AlastairMaw Agreed. Not sure who downvoted your answer, but I suspect it's because you didn't quite answer the question, instead changing the question and answering _that_.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but I'll share what my English teacher taught us:

"Between" (in the sense of to "choose between" or "divide between") **strictly** applies when there are exactly **two** things to choose or divide between.

"Among" is used **strictly** when there are **more** than two.